# dynamically create multiple textboxes C#

Tags: c#, textbox

This is my code. 
But all my textboxes's value is just null.

```
    public void createTxtTeamNames()
    {
        TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[teams];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (TextBox txt in txtTeamNames)
        {
            string name = "TeamNumber" + i.ToString();
            txt.Name = name;
            txt.Text = name;
            txt.Location = new Point(172, 32 + (i * 28));
            txt.Visible = true;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The array creation call just initializes the elements to `null`.  You need to individually create them.

```
TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[teams];
for (int i = 0; i < txtTeamNames.Length; i++) {
  var txt = new TextBox();
  txtTeamNames[i] = txt;
  txt.Name = name;
  txt.Text = name;
  txt.Location = new Point(172, 32 + (i * 28));
  txt.Visible = true;
}
```

Note: As several people have pointed out in order for this code to be meaningful you will need to add each `TextBox` to a parent `Control`. eg `this.Controls.Add(txt)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your textbox at the start of the loop.

You also need to use a for loop instead of a foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to new up your TextBoxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < teams; i++)
{
    txtTeamNames[i] = new TextBox();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you have to add textbox instances to the array, and then add it to the form. This is how you should do it.

```
public void createTxtTeamNames()
        {
            TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[10];

for (int u = 0; u < txtTeamNames.Count(); u++)
            {
                txtTeamNames[u] = new TextBox();
            }
            int i = 0;
            foreach (TextBox txt in txtTeamNames)
            {
                string name = "TeamNumber" + i.ToString();

                txt.Name = name;
                txt.Text = name;
                txt.Location = new Point(0, 32 + (i * 28));
                txt.Visible = true;
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = abc;
        tb.Text = "" + i;

        Point p = new Point(20 + i, 30 * i);
        tb.Location = p;
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        i++;
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBox item in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Name + ": " + item.Text + "\\n");   
        }
    }
```