# how to make list of user control and this list contains a new list of another user control c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

i have created a user control and this user control is contain a button that when i click it it should show a new form and this form would contains a new user control ...... the problem is that when i created a list of the first user control i want to link this list with another list of another user control 
or if there is another solution to list the first user control with the second user control ?

this is the lists that i should link together ... i have tried to make a 2D List but i couldn't

```
 List<Cate> Category = new List<Cate>();
 List<products> ProductUC = new List<products>();
```

the first user control which its name is Cate contrain a button i made this code to show another form

```
  for (int j = 0; j < Data.BTN_Name.Count; j++)
        {
            var captured_j = j;  // to get the index of clicked Button
            Category[j].Controls[1].Click += (s, ea) => FrmProduct[captured_j].ShowDialog();

        }
```

and this new form should be contains a list of another user controls which can be created dynamically 
and here is a screen shot for more explanation 
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500870240094

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access a member of one control from another control and vice versa?

Comment: no .... i want to link a user control with a list of another user control

Comment: the first form of the project contains a list of user control ... and every element of this list contains a list of another user control

Comment: OK, so do you mean that you want to add a usercontrol to the form, and then add a usercontrol to that usercontrol programmatically?

Comment: yes but i need to add many user controls dynamically to the first user control..... i know how to add user control to another programmatically ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating winforms controls dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633826/creating-winforms-controls-dynamically)

Comment: The duplicate should help you achieve that. You can't use `List` as `Control` objects (form, usercontrol, etc.) have a `Controls` collection which you have to add to.

Comment: look .... i need this cause my project contains categories and each category contains some products .... i want to link their user controls cause i need to save their data in file

Comment: So is your question about dynamically generating UI or not? If yes, the duplicate I linked you to will help.

Comment: may be you don't understood my problem ? @john

Comment: I don't. You don't make your problem clear. You say it's not about accessing a member of one control from another, so it must be about dynamically generating UI. And then you say it's not about generating UI. What is your question about?

Comment: i know how to dynamically generate but it isn't the problem XD

Comment: this is the main problem..... how to make list of user control and this list contains a new list of another user control c#?

Comment: Do you mean `List<UserControl>` or do you mean a list that _belongs to_ another user control?

Comment: yeah i mean a list that belongs to another user control

Comment: OK, can you _edit your question_ and add the code for how you add your usercontrol to the UI, and then how your "link" should behave (i.e. should it trigger a method in the child control, should it access a member of the child control - a list or something - and take a copy of its values, etc.).

Comment: @john okay i will

Comment: is now the problem more clear ?@john