# C# Add 2d array to tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2d array and how i can add this 2d array to tablelayoutpanel?

```
string[,] mayinlar = new string[20, 20];
        for(int i = 0; i < mayin ; i++)
        {
            int j = rnd.Next(0, 20);
            int k = rnd.Next(0, 20);
            mayinlar[j, k] = "x";
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear enough, Do you want to show your array in WinForm control like DataGridView or what?

Comment: I want make a minesweeper and im create 2d array for mines so i want show this mines on tablelayoutpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as simple as you asked for, but I can help you to show 2D array in a form.
1. Add a Listbox control and rename it to listBox1. (It's default name)
2. Add this code :

```
string x = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++)
    {
        x += (mayinlar[i, j])?.Length == 1 ? mayinlar[i, j] : " ";
    }
    listBox1.Items.Add(x);
    x = null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for it but i cant use listbox because i making a minesweeper.

Comment: Making a game like minesweeper needs programming skills, So you have a good start.
this link helps you to create form control in run-time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633826/creating-winforms-controls-dynamically

Comment: What do you think I should use? But button will not be used i will use arrow keys and dont have to steps mines.

Comment: Microsoft Minesweeper implemented blocks with button, But in a modern way, you can use System.Drawing namespace.
this link provides you with the complete solution:https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Minesweeper_game