# List data to textboxes

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I want to put the data of a list in to textboxes.

I am new in C# and come up with this solution.
This works fine if you only have 5 lines but it's going to be way more.
Is there a better solution in c#

```
private void saveBotton_CopyToListbox1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (invoerBox1.Text != "")
    {
        Outbox.Items.Add(invoerBox1.Text);                        
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 3)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = Outbox.Items[2].ToString();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 4)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = Outbox.Items[2].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = Outbox.Items[3].ToString();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 5)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = Outbox.Items[2].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = Outbox.Items[3].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = Outbox.Items[4].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and at delete of an index

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Outbox.SelectedIndex >=0)
    {
        Outbox.Items.RemoveAt(Outbox.SelectedIndex);
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Clear();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Clear();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 3)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = Outbox.Items[2].ToString();
            textBox4.Clear();
        }
        if (Outbox.Items.Count == 4)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Outbox.Items[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = Outbox.Items[1].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = Outbox.Items[2].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = Outbox.Items[3].ToString();
            textBox5.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create dynamic TextBoxes from code behind. Check this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generate-textbox-dynamically-at-runtime-in-windows-form-application1

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368748/dynamically-create-multiple-textboxes-c-sharp