# How to add listBoxes to a list of listBoxes in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to add to list boxes to a List of list boxes in a loop instead of adding each one manually in my code.

Would like to use a for loop and add the item to my list like below.

```
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox[i])
```

instead of...

```
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox1);
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox2);
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox3);
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox4);
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox5);
listOfListBoxes.Add(listBox6);
```

Comment: Where are these `ListBox's` defined at or coming from? Have you tried a `for` if so what is the issue?

Comment: This is a common scneanrio with WinForms and Web Based scenarios.   For Winforms see these two questions and answers .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633826/creating-winforms-controls-dynamically         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368748/dynamically-create-multiple-textboxes-c-sharp       For Web you can use repeaters or "grid" template scenarios.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++) { if (Controls[i] is ListBox) listOfListBoxes.Add(Controls[i] as ListBox); }`

Comment: @RufusL or somewhat a little shorter `(Controls[i] is ListBox lBox)`... then just add the `lBox` to the list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your listboxes are defined in a Form (this). So you can simply get all the listboxes from the Controls collection with this line and add them with AddRange

```
listOfListBoxes.AddRange(this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>());
```

The Controls collection contains all the controls of your form defined at design time and created with the InitializeComponent call. This collection could be used in a loop and checked for every element if it is a ListBox with something like this code

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    ListBox lb = c as ListBox;
    if(lb != null) 
        listOfListBoxes.Add(lb);    
}
```

but the introduction of the [IEnumerable extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) in the namespace Linq has given the opportunity to avoid the explicit loop above and use the extension [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) that does the loop internally and yields each element of the type requested.
Finally you could add all these elements returned by OfType as an array to List.AddRange method

Comment: Introducing linq may not be something the OP understands (maybe a good time to learn), maybe should have clarified and waited on OP to show what they have done so things can be clarified. Currently it's a good solution of course, but doesn't explain at all if possible what would be wrong with what they have attempted.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly was I was wanting to do.